# special characters within a variable

Tags: php

Can I store a special character inside a variable?

I mean something like:

```
<?php
$variable='&nbsp;&nbsp;'
```

Then can i use something like echo $variable?

Comment: -1 for not taking the 3 seconds required to test this

Comment: Ok I admit Hobodave..  it just struck my mind and thought to ask ..

Comment: hobodave, your edit changes the question completely. You have taken his characters and then html encoded them.

Comment: Sam152 you clearly didn't look at the original source. He put in &nbsp; Because it wasn't formatted as a code block the browser translated the non breaking space. please do not revert my edit again.

Comment: Additionally a simple application of critical thinking should make you question who would consider a space a "special character"

Comment: @hobodave: an `&nbsp;` is not just a normal space. it's a non-breaking space, which is different.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but don't take my word for it:

```
#!/path/to/php
<?
$variable = '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
echo $variable;
?>
```

Comment: What is #!/path/to/php ? This is not Perl.

Comment: Really? Is that why I said /path/to/php? http://www.php-cli.com/ As of  PHP 4 you can run PHP scripts just like you can perl, bash, etc., by specifying the interpreter at the top of the file.  I hope I wasn't downvoted for you not knowing that...